# Get single value using inner join

Tags: php, mysql, database, inner-join

I have a two tables calldetails and calltype

**calldetails table**

```
id calltype isactive
1   1       1
2   1       1
3   1       1
```

**Calltype table**

```
id name             isactive
1  mobile internet   1
```

**Expected Result**

```
id name             isactive
1  mobile internet   1
```

but i got i below result

```
id name             isactive
1  mobile internet   1
1  mobile internet   1
1  mobile internet   1
```

I have used below query

```
SELECT ct.`name` , ct.`id`
FROM calltype AS ct
INNER JOIN calldetails AS cd ON cd.`isactive` =1
WHERE ct.`isactive` =1
AND ct.`id` = cd.`calltype`
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

How to get single value using inner join.

Comment: DISTINCT might be a way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT ct.`name` , ct.`id`
FROM calltype AS ct
INNER JOIN calldetails AS cd ON cd.`isactive` =1
WHERE ct.`isactive` =1
AND ct.`id` = cd.`calltype`
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use distinct on the select from the calldetails :

```
SELECT ct.`name` , ct.`id`
FROM calltype AS ct
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT calltype, isactive FROM calldetails) cd ON cd.`isactive` =1
WHERE ct.`isactive` =1
AND ct.`id` = cd.`calltype`
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
SELECT ct.`name` , ct.`id`
FROM calltype AS ct
INNER JOIN calldetails AS cd ON cd.`isactive` = ct.`isactive`
WHERE ct.`isactive` =1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Here is a link to check inner join command:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp